# c++ - Multithreading serial port

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, serial-port

I currently need to write a Windows 10 application that collects data from four different sensors (encoders and IMUs) via serial. I am writing this in Visual Studio in c++.

Each sensor requires me to write to it once to initialize it and then just read values. I was thinking of having a thread for each sensor (i.e. serial port) and a main thread to gather all of the data and save it in a file.

In other Stack Overflow questions, however, people have suggested having a thread to write and another to read, or a single threaded overlapped approach.

What are the pros/cons of this versus multithreaded? And if I do choose the multithreaded path do I need to use overlapped I/O or can I do non-overlapped?

Windows documentation states that for non-overlapped:

> If one thread is blocked waiting for its I/O operation to complete, all other threads that subsequently call a communications API will be blocked until the original operation completes. For instance, if one thread were waiting for a ReadFile function to return, any other thread that issued a WriteFile function would be blocked.

Is this still true if I am using different serial ports for each sensor? Since I need to read these values as fast as possible I cannot afford blocking.

Any help is appreciated! This is my first time designing a system...

Comment: How are you intending to use the gathered information? If you have processing that depends on readings from all the sensors I'd use overlapped IO Because you will have fewer synchonization problems. If each sensor lives in it's own little works and does not interact with the result of data from the other sensors,  and you have a recent enough Visual Studio to support `std::thread`, multithreaded with each thread blocking and  and listening should be simpler.

Comment: @user4581301 All the sensors are independent from each other, and data processing occurs outside of the scope of this program. So if this were multithreaded with non-overlapped I/O, threads wouldn't block each other?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to shut up on this one. Having hunted down the document from which the quote you cite, what they describe is either poorly worded or a freaking nightmare. I am unsure whether they mean if you block on access to a serial port, all serial ports are blocked or just the one serial port. The first seems insane. I need to experiment.

Comment: Experimented and find that I can have multiple threads simultaneously talking to different serial ports.

Comment: Test consisted of two threats starting, then sleeping for a second while the main thread blocked on a read to COM1 that would never complete because no timeout was set and no device was present to respond. Two other threads opened COM3 and COM4 respectively. Each sent a request to the attached device and then performed a blocking read while waiting for the response.

Comment: Bonus: I found a bug in the Windows port of my serial wrapper. Thanks!

Comment: *"people have suggested having a thread to write and another to read"* -- IMO that's a rarely-needed  design.  The device on the other end that you're communicating with is very likely single threaded rather than R/W multi-threaded.  The typical dialog on a serial link is a series of request-response messages.  The serial link is rarely used like a network connection.  Additionally, the OS always buffers the receive data from the UART, so the application does not have to be executing or "ready" to "read" the data.  Your original plan of a thread to service each serial port makes sense.

Comment: *"Windows documentation states that ... call a communications API..."* -- I interpret that to apply on a per-device or per-controller basis.  Once an I/O operation is started, other operations on that device/controller have to wait.  The serial ports are independent devices (even if there's a USB hub involved).  Read and write operations to serial ports are independent operations and do not interact (soft flow-control might be the exception).